# problem with Styler.highlight_min and scientific notation, in a dataframe of string

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a jupyter lab and I have an example like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1.', '5', '3', ], 
                       'B': ['2', '4',  '5e-3']})
df.style.highlight_min(color='yellow',axis=1)
```

where I want to highlight for each row the minimum.

The problem is that for the last row it is highlighting 3 instead of 5e-3.
It would work if I convert all to floats but the original dataframe is much more complex and I'd rather not touch the content.

I had in mind to convert to a second fully numeric df and then map back the obtained min values. It is feasible but I was wondering if there is something I am missing

maybe this is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not %100 ideal, but does the job well:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1.', '5', '3'], 
                   'B': ['2', '4', '5e-3']})

# Numeric Version of dataframe to handle numeric computations
df_numeric = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)# You can add errors="coerce" to handle non-convertable values as NAN

# Get the minimum value for each row
min_values = df_numeric.min(axis=1)

#Dummy dataframe to hold background color information
df_dummy = pd.DataFrame("", index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

for i, min_val in enumerate(min_values):
    min_index = df_numeric.iloc[i].eq(min_val)
    df_dummy.iloc[i] = ["background-color: yellow" if x else "" for x in min_index]
    
df = df.style.apply(lambda _: df_dummy, axis=None)

df
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Very useful to know how to map back the pattern. Thanks! ... Not as clever of an option wolololand could have also considered: Could also skip everything after df_numeric step here and use `df_numeric.style.highlight_min(color='yellow',axis=1).format('{:.1e}')` to represent all in notation. "the original dataframe is much more complex and I'd rather not touch the content." A Pandas styler doesn't touch the dataframe & so no chance original content touched. (But maybe the styled version is what wolololand is continuing on to use. I'm just mentioning it because maybe others won't be doing that.)

Comment: @Wayne , good idea indeed but I avoided solutions like that because, I dont think It would end up in a result that he wished for i.e keeping 2 as 2 and 5e-3 as 5e-3 . In your version some numbers will lose their original format.

Comment: Totally agree. Your solution is absolutely the best in the case put forth here. I ran out of space in my comment though. In place of "to represent all in notation" I would rather have said "to represent all values in consistent scientific notation". Again, I'm only adding this as an option for others that may find this post given the topic and want an option to apply a consistent formatting for viewing only in parallel while leaving the real data actually untouched.

Comment: @Wayne , I see, I agree with you as well. It was again a good idea to include your option for others that might find this post.

Comment: @CemKoçak this is brilliant, thanks! I will accept this as it does exactly what the question was asking for. However, by experimenting with this and trying to do also with max in a second for loop, it does not work as, I believe, the `else ""` part is overwriting the previous style.

Comment: @Wayne, yes I dont want to lose the formatting of the numbers, and in the original dataframe I have also strings, which would be no correctly parsed. I apply this style in a subset of rows.

Comment: @wolololand I have included a second answer for what you are trying to achieve now. Hope it helps :)  If you need further help you can create a new question and share its link with me on the comments, I will do my best to answer. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment to my answer, I see you are now also trying to color max values. I decided to include another answer for that. As a side note even if this answer works for your new task, I highly suggest not accepting it as the answer and instead keep my first answer as accepted, this will be more benefical and less confusing to possible future visitors with smilar problem.

To include coloring of max values in the row as well:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1.', '5', '3'], 
                   'B': ['2', '4', '5e-3']})

# Numeric Version of dataframe to handle numeric computations
df_numeric = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)

# Get the minimum and maximum values for each row
min_values = df_numeric.min(axis=1)
max_values = df_numeric.max(axis=1)

# Dummy dataframe to hold background color information
df_dummy = pd.DataFrame("", index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

# Minimum values in yellow and maximum values in blue
for i, (min_value, max_value) in enumerate(zip(min_values, max_values)):
    min_index = df_numeric.iloc[i].eq(min_value)
    max_index = df_numeric.iloc[i].eq(max_value)
    df_dummy.iloc[i] = ["background-color: yellow" if x else "background-color: blue" if y else "" for x, y in zip(min_index, max_index)]
    
df = df.style.apply(lambda _: df_dummy, axis=None)

df
```

Output:
[image]

Would still work if there were more than 2 columns present. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1.', '5', '3'], 
                   'B': ['2', '4', '5e-3'],
                   'C':["3","6","0.1"]})
```

Results in output:

[image]